# Python Type is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I want to do the semantic checking for a language and i use ANTLR4 to generate parser and visitor class. However i met a problem.
If i use this method `print(type(newList[0].expression()))`
I will get a type like this `<class 'IDILParser.IDILParser.IdenetExpressionContext'>`
However, if i run the code below, i will get a error like this `NameError: name 'IDILParser' is not defined`
Can i ask how to fix this problem? Thanks!

```
from antlr4 import *
if __name__ is not None and "." in __name__:    
    from .IDILParser import IDILParser
else:
    from IDILParser import IDILParser

class IDILVisitor(ParseTreeVisitor):
    def visitAssign(self, ctx:IDILParser.AssignContext):
        if type(newList[0].expression()) is IDILParser.IDILParser.IdenetExpressionContext:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `from IDILParser import IDILParser`, which means the *IDILParser* in your code already acutally refers to `IDILParser.IDILParser`.

So try taking away that one layer:

```
if type(newList[0].expression()) is IDILParser.IdenetExpressionContext:
    ...
```

Btw, when in doubt if your code is being run as a module or as a script (aka relative imports do work or not), you could also do the following:

```
try:
    from .IDILParser import IDILParser
except ImportError:
    from IDILParser import IDILParser
```

Comment: I want to check that the type of newList[0].expression() is IDILParser.IdenetExpressionContext. Can i ask how to do it? Thx!

Comment: Did you try my code from above? Note that the first **IDILParser** is removed.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I have a similar problem. @Jeronimo your solution doesn't work. "NameError", name 'IdilParser' is not defined.